# How to get the analytical solution or numerical solution of the double integral

Tags: numerical-integration, version-7, calculus-and-analysis

i just want to calculate this double integral but can't get the analytical solution,so it there a way to get the analytical solution or numerical solution of the double integral?

codes are as this

```
k = 1.71504;
a = 0.1;
T0 = 1.575;
omega = 2*\[Pi]/T0;

t = 1;

integral = 
 NIntegrate[
  Integrate[Cos[k*r*Cos[theta] - omega*t]*r, {r, 0, a}], {theta, 0, 
   2*\[Pi]}, MaxRecursion -> 100]
```

[image]

and i have updated my question and the hints are as this

```
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 100 recursive bisections in theta near {theta} = {1.5708}. NIntegrate obtained -0.138032+0. I and 0.024293035647033348` for the integral and error estimates. >>
```

in fact i just don't want to assign the variable time `t`,so if i don't assign `t`,can i get the integral solution of a function of `t`?

Comment: If numeric solution is enough, then it should be straightforward to solve this with `NIntegrate`. Which part are you having difficulty?

Comment: i have updated my  question and the integral function is `Cos[k*r*Cos[theta] - omega*t]*r` rather than`Cos[k*r*Cos[theta - omega*t]]*r`

Comment: A single `NIntegrate` is enough. Please check the document of `NIntegrate` carefully.

Comment: Your code runs without error on v12!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann,i have updated the codes and have you use the updated codes`k = 1.71504;
a = 0.1;
T0 = 1.575;
omega = 2*\[Pi]/T0;

t = 1;

integral = 
 NIntegrate[
  Integrate[Cos[k*r*Cos[theta] - omega*t]*r, {r, 0, a}], {theta, 0, 
   2*\[Pi]}, MaxRecursion -> 100]`

Comment: @dcydhb See my answer, I used the updated parameters. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
k = 1.71504; a = 0.1; T0 = 1.575; omega = 2*\[Pi]/T0;
int[t_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[Cos[k*r*Cos[theta] - omega*t]*r, {r, 0, a}, {theta, 0, 2*\[Pi]}, MaxRecursion -> 100]
```

to get the time dependent integral.

```
Plot[int[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

Without predefined parameters Mathematica can solve analytically!

```
Clear[k, a, T0, omega]
Integrate[Cos[k*r*Cos[theta] - omega*t]*r, {r, 0, a}, {theta, 0, 2*\[Pi]}]
(*a^2 \[Pi] Cos[omega t] Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -(1/4) a k Conjugate[a] Conjugate[k]]*)
```

The time dependent part of the solution is `Cos[omega t]` (as expected from the numerical solution)

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: and  it seems i have got this result `(2 a \[Pi] BesselJ[1,a k] Cos[omega t])/k` and when `Conjugate[a]=a and Conjugate[k]=k`,they are the same.

Comment: @dcydhb You're welcome!